# Where do you download oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar?

Tags: java, oracle, ssl

I am trying to connect Oracle over SSL using thin JDBC driver. I have wallet configurations available. But when I am trying to connect to Oracle from a Java program, I am getting

```
To use 'connect /' functionality, oraclepki.jar must be in the classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet
```

Most of the solutions are pointing towards adding jars  oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar  but I am not able to find a place from where to download those.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These jars can be found in your Oracle Database installation.

They can also be found in the [Oracle Maven Repository](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) or on the [Oracle JDBC download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Alternately, these jars are available on Oracle Maven repository.  You can refer to this blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Nirmala It worked. The page you mentioned is quite helpful. A suggestion, it would be great if you could add exact maven dependencies xml for each jar.  I felt it was not that quite intuitive.  Thanks

Comment: can also download them as part of the ojdbc tarball on the jdbc download page.

Answer (score 0):

Check jdk or jre. 
jre have oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar, but jdk doesn't.

I think you might be used jdk in part for jre in IDE.